# showing data frame in igraph

Tags: r, igraph

my data frame is called

p

```
Impacted_system, Application_Caused_Incident Number_of_Incident                   
Web                  Financials        10                   
PeopleSoft           HR                30
PPP                  PeopleSoft        50
```

etc

I like to show igraph diagram having the edges to be impacted Systems, edges having text in showing the impacted_system and the Number of incidents.

I did this:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(p)
plot.igraph(g)
```

I get graph with edges having numbers. I relly like to see the text like HR, Web  and the number of incidents on edges etc. any ideas?

Comment: I would start with this resource here, focusing on print.edge.attributes: http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/igraph.par.html

Comment: @tcash21, I did something like this g <- graph.data.frame(p) and plot(g,  layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,  vertex.label = V(g)$name), it looks like it is on the right directions. I would like to show the number_of_incidents on the arrows. Any idea, how I would do this. This is really cool.

Comment: I got it, its edge.label

Comment: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2012-10/msg00023.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this worked:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(p)
plot(g,  layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold,  vertex.label = V(g)$name)
```